# IE VBA How to click on a SVG element

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, svg

My goal is to automate the process that requires going into a certain website, enter a BOL number and then click on search button in order to consult a document.

I haven't been able to click on the search button.

```
Dim oBrowser As Object
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With oBrowser


            'Open Browser
            .navigate "https://www.paquetexpress.com.mx/rastreo-de-envios" 
            .Visible = 1
            Do While .readyState <> 4:
            DoEvents:
            Loop
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))


            'Enter BOL Number
            Set HTMLdoc = .document
            Set htmlColl = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
            Do While HTMLdoc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
            For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
                If htmlInput.Name = "trackingguides" Then
                     htmlInput.Value = "10101010101"
                     Exit For
                End If
            Next htmlInput


'************* I'm having issues with this section **************

            'Click Search
            Set HTMLdoc = .document
            Set htmlColl = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")
            x = 1
            Do While HTMLdoc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop


            For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
                    If InStr(1, htmlInput.outerHTML, "0 0 16 16") > 0 Then
                            If htmlInput.offsetTop > 5 Then
                                htmlInput.Click
                                Exit For
                            End If
                    End If
            Next htmlInput

  '**************************************************************
End With
```

Comment: I try to debug your code on my side and I find that your code is clicking the button but nothing happened on the site. If I manually paste the value in textbox and click the button than also nothing happened on the site. In console, I got CORS related message and other errors. https://imgur.com/a/Ka5wSAu So please try to check on your side whether you are able to do this manually and whether you get any errors or not. it can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: When I do it manually it allows me to see an error message on the webpage since "10101010101" is just a random number. When I run the macro, I don't even get to that point. It does nothing other than introducing the number in the textbox.

Comment: Can you please again try to debug your code with correct input? Please check that on which line your code get stuck and does it give any error or warning message at that time? It can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the site and what you are trying to do, this should work:

`HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("svg-icon svg-fill")(1).Click`

Answer (score 0):

This would be an optimized method but page seems to hang for me

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, event_onClick As Object

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.paquetexpress.com.mx/rastreo-de-envios"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            Set event_onClick = .createEvent("HTMLEvents")
            event_onClick.initEvent "click", True, False
            .querySelector("#tracking__input__container input").Value = "10101010101"
            With .querySelector(".searchicon")
                .FireEvent "onclick"
                .dispatchEvent event_onClick
            End With
        End With
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr. I'm still having issues with the search button. I can't click it.

Comment: There's an event attached. You could try .FireEvent or attaching an event as shown in edit above.

Comment: Do you think that an index number should be introduced? Should use "focus" as well?

Comment: I will need to look again at some point. Unsure as the page doesn't respond well even when manually performing the tasks. Does it always behave as expected when you manually do this? I am thinking poor design at present in part. And no, no index required.